# XCode flagging type errors in NSData+Base64.m

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Error is as shown in below image
[image]

```
- (id) initWithBase64EncodedString:(NSString *) string {
    NSMutableData *mutableData = nil;

    if( string ) {
        unsigned long ixtext = 0;
        unsigned long lentext = 0;
        unsigned char ch = 0;
        unsigned char inbuf[4], outbuf[4];
        short i = 0, ixinbuf = 0;
        BOOL flignore = NO;
        BOOL flendtext = NO;
        NSData *base64Data = nil;
        const unsigned char *base64Bytes = nil;

        // Convert the string to ASCII data.
        base64Data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        base64Bytes = [base64Data bytes];
        mutableData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:[base64Data length]];
        lentext = [base64Data length];

    }
```

And also i am getting in another method named as

```
- (NSString *) base64EncodingWithLineLength:(unsigned int) lineLength {
    **const unsigned char   *bytes = [self bytes];**
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[self length]];
```

}
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve that error by type casting...but not sure data is in same formate..

```
    base64Bytes = (const unsigned char*)[base64Data bytes];
```

Comment: Hi @Raj can u please guide me the error in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033500/xcode-flag-error-in-mgtwitterengine-m  (3rd image)

Comment: Hello Raj  do u  know this,. what type of error it is?  in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033500/xcode-flag-error-in-mgtwitterengine-m 3rd image.... @Raj