# XCode flag error in MGTwitterEngine.m

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am getting error in MGTwitterEngine.m as shown in the image
[image]

I am unable to find where the mistake is.. 
Please guide me

Thanks a lot in advance

and also error in MGTTwitterLibXMLParser.m as shown in below image

[image]

error in SA_OAuthTwitterController.m

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uncomment these lines, because the assigned variables are unused. As seen in the comment `Dump XML to file for debugging.`

Comment: ok.. Thank u so much .. can u please tell me the error i got in MGTTwitterLibXMLParser.m .. i updated the question @btype

Comment: i added the header search path also in targets and also included the libxml2 @btype

Comment: I have no idea, but you can consider using http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html because MGTwitterEngine is kind of outdated (last update 2 years ago)

Comment: can u please show the 3rd image and guide me to that error ...... i resolved 2 errors from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989112/xcode-flagging-type-errors-in-nsdatabase64-m  but i unable to solve this  please Guide me  @btype

Comment: HI.. can u plz look at the above commented error  i.e., (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989112/xcode-flagging-type-errors-in-nsdatabase64-m) 3rd image @btype

Comment: char *raw; if (data){ raw = (char *)[data bytes];} Think the problem is on the two " in the else case.